# SOOldCheckmark - Bring back the old checkmark!

Tags: script, greasemonkey

Here on Stack Overflow, [we hate change, especially regarding the new checkmark color](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/185401/who-stole-the-darkness-from-the-accepted-answer-tick). So, I have the perfect solution to all of our needs - bring back the old goodness!

Contained in the user script, is simply a base64'd version of the *old* checkmark sprite.

Here's a screenshot of it in action:

[image]

## [Click to install me!](https://raw.github.com/richardjrossiii/Stack-Overflow-User-Scripts/master/SOOldCheckmark.user.js) <sub>([view source](https://github.com/richardjrossiii/Stack-Overflow-User-Scripts/blob/master/SOOldCheckmark.user.js?nogreasemonkey=true))</sub>

Comment: I can't install the extension due to Chrome's "security" rules. Google Chrome shows me this help page: https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769?p=crx_warning&rd=1

Comment: @ComFreek I suggest you get a better browser :) I do not support chrome and do not plan to, sorry. There is an equivalent chrome extension available here, though: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/185430/151015

Answer (score 2):

Nice one-liner! Personally, I like the new "funky" green, but good job nonetheless!

Here's a more comprehensive `@include` list you can use:

```
// @include     http://*.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @include     http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/*
// @include     http://askubuntu.com/questions/*
// @include     http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/*
// @include     http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/*
// @include     http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @include     http://serverfault.com/questions/*
// @include     https://stackapps.com/questions/*
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @include     http://superuser.com/questions/*
```

An up-to-date list is available at [Complete list of sites to @include / @match into my script?](https://stackapps.com/questions/4188/complete-list-of-sites-to-include-match-into-my-script)