# Complete list of sites to @include / @match into my script?

Tags: support, scripts

This question aims to serve as a reference list of all current Stack Exchange sites for use in scripts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stack Exchange userscript template / boilerplate](http://stackapps.com/questions/4790/stack-exchange-userscript-template-boilerplate). It's basically the same thing but that one has other helpful answers around the topic

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to support alias domains.  They redirect to `*.stackexchange.com` domains, anyway.

This will match all current Stack Exchange sites.  It uses `@match` for smarter domain and path wildcards.  [`@match` also works better for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16413467/331508):

```
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/*
```

---

Although, for slightly better speed and to help avoid unexpected results, **you should also exclude some sites** (Namely: The API, the main blogs<sup>1</sup>, SEDE, and the "all sites" pages) unless you are specifically coding for them. Their structure and purpose is markedly different.

**So use:**

```
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/*
// @exclude     *://api.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://blog.*.com/*
// @exclude     *://chat.*.com/*
// @exclude     *://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://elections.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://openid.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://stackexchange.com/*
```

As a practical start for most scripts.

---

Note that [onstartups no longer needs to be supported.](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12607/site-on-startups-is-closed-what-to-do-now)

<sup>1</sup> The "not so main" blogs are all/mostly on a separate domain: `blogoverflow.com`.