# Force Edit suggested reviews

Tags: script, editing

[image]

Review edits have the option to force edit, which will edit the original post, as opposed to improve which will edit the suggested edit.

UserScript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Force edit suggested reviews Stackoverflow
// @namespace     stackoverflow
// @description   Allows you to bypass reviewing suggested edits and just edit
// @include       http://stackoverflow.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    function with_jquery(f) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    with_jquery(function ($) {
        $("a[id^=edit-pending-]").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id').substr(13),
                href = $(this).attr('href');
            $(this).replaceWith('<a id="edit-pending-' + id + '" href="' + href + '" title="1 edit to this post is pending, please review it">review edit (1)</a><span class="lsep">|</span><a href="/posts/' + id + '/edit" class="edit-post" title="force edit this post">force edit</a>');
        });
    });

}());
```

Comment: How did you create such a nice animated gif? I tried to used ffmpeg, but the output was horrible...

Comment: @PaulSweatte [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) with a framerate of 30. For a small demonstration, the filesize is usually small ~200-300kb.

Comment: LICEcap, never heard of it until now. It generates animated gifs by default, so no conversion needed. Thanks!

Comment: This would be a lot easier for people not familiar with user scripts to use if you provided a direct link to the raw file (e.g. on GitHub). That would save people from needing to copy-and-paste the code into a new script.

Comment: The `@include` needs to be `*://stackoverflow.com` these days to activate on `https` as well.  (Too short an edit for me to suggest though :)

Comment: I'm flagging to close this question because this script has become obsolete due to SE changes and cannot be fixed to work again. This script relied on the fact that the only checks for a pending suggestion were client-side, so it was possible to defeat this easily. Today, however, there's now a server-side check, so navigating the page to the edit URL manually as this script does won't work anymore.

Comment: It could probably be fixed by making a trivial edit (appending a space somewhere)? Not that I want to encourage that practice, but still ...

Answer (score 2):

As written, the script functions only on Stack Overflow.  You can make it work on all Stack Exchange sites by changing the [Metadata Block](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block) (the part at the beginning of the script) to the following:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Force edit suggested reviews
// @namespace     stackoverflow
// @description   Allows you to bypass reviewing suggested edits and just edit
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/*
// @exclude     *://api.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://blog.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://blog.stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude     *://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://chat.stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude     *://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://elections.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://stackexchange.com/*
// ==/UserScript==
```

The source for the `// @match` and `// @exclude` statements is [Brock Adams' answer here](https://stackapps.com/a/4190/29529).

Comment: Regex `@includes` will have inferior performance. See http://stackapps.com/questions/4188/complete-list-of-sites-to-include-match-into-my-script ... Also, restricting the path to `/questions` may skip some review pages.

Comment: @BrockAdams, I've changed this because I clearly messed up original regexes. While functional, they were just...bad (I'm not sure what I was thinking when I wrote them). At least for the moment, I've changed it to use the `@match` and `@exclude` lines from your linked answer, and am considering just deleting this answer.

Comment: @BrockAdams, wrt. including `questions` in the match: I am unaware of any pending edit links from review pages. Are there? I don't recall ever seeing such links. I only recall ever seeing pending edit links on actual `questions` pages. Matching only `question` pages was intentional. I've removed that criteria under the assumption I'm wrong and pending edit links exist somewhere else.

Comment: @BrockAdams, I'm aware that using regex `@include` will have some unknown inferior performance vs. a similar number of `@matches`. I've never seen anything that actually quantifies the difference. It's unclear to me if there is actually a significant performance improvement to use 7 `@matches` and 8 `@excludes` vs a single `@include` regex [note: multiple `@include` statements were being used here instead of 1 because Tampermonkey does not parse a single regex sufficiently to show multiple site logos in it's dashboard]. (continued)

Comment: @BrockAdams, I suspect that any performance difference may depend significantly on if the RegExp is compiled once per script change or if they are recompiled for each page load (same quandary for the potentially complex `@matches`/`@exclude`). Do you know of any reported *quantified* difference, or have you looked at the Tampermonkey and/or Greasemonkey code to see if the RegExp compile is every page, or every script change?

Comment: As for the `/question` path, I think I remember a scenario that applied, but not enough to say for sure.  Note that I *did* use the weasel word "may". ;)

Comment: `@match` performs better.  This is covered in various GM discussions which you can search out and also by analysis of the code. Also `@match` regex is "safed". Finally, @match gives proper indication in the Tampermonkey dashboard of matched sites.  `@include` does not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56396/discussion-between-makyen-and-brock-adams).