# How do I future-proof my app to work with every SE site?

Tags: support, sites

I just wrote an app for Chrome extensions and received a request to make it cross-StackExchange compatible.

If there's eventually going to be more sites than just the few listed and I don't really know what they'll be called other than by checking here every so often to see what is supported, how do I future-proof my app to work with every SE site? Or am I doomed to hardcode everything?

Answer (score 2):

This question is nearly a duplicate of [Complete list of sites to @include / @match into my script?](https://stackapps.com/questions/4188/complete-list-of-sites-to-include-match-into-my-script).

This is not hard. There are only seven [second-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name#Second-level_and_lower_level_domains) to worry about and **[all new sites are likely to continue using a domain in the `*.stackexchange.com` pattern.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/13/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/)**  See the above linked question for the list.

But if you are especially paranoid, you can [check the site list via the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=999&filter=!SmNnfXy34WIqvjrFxk) every month or two.

---

See, also: [Can we have a list of all the Stack Exchange domains somewhere, for firewall purposes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81379/can-we-have-a-list-of-all-the-stack-exchange-domains-somewhere-for-firewall-pur)