# Automatically add OP's name in comments on StackExchange sites

Tags: script, comments

## Automatically add OP's name in comments on StackExchange sites

Converts `[user]` in a comment to be posted to the OP's username. Originally created to allow comment snippets with `[user]` included to be copy-pasted.

### Installation

- Install [the userscript](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/373250-user-to-op-s-name-on-stackexchange-sites).

<sub>Developed & tested with TamperMonkey on Chrome.</sub>

Comment: Regarding the feature-requests you keep getting, see https://stackapps.com/a/4190/7653.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Should probably exclude `chat` so that it isn't running unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

When pasting into an answer, it'll take the name of the OP on the question, not the answerer.

[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUKur.gif)

Comment: This was actually intended, but I will change the behavior when I find some time

Comment: I edited the code so if you put "user" it says the name on the post you are commenting and if you put "USER" it will put the OP's.

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It doesn't take into account the International SO sites.

Should add:

```
// @match        https://*.stackoverflow.com/*
```